# How to avoid destroy deleting earlier related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If the user already has a favorite model after log in, then I want the products that were added to their anonymous bookmarks to be overwritten in the favorite that is attached to their user object.

I find `session_favorite` (anonymous favorite), `@favorite`, which belongs to the user. I am rewriting `line_item.favorite` with the ID of `session_favorite` to the user's ID favorite. I reset the session and destroy that anonymous favorite, which in theory has become empty, since now `line_items` has the user's favorite ID.

But, for some reason, when destroying a `session_favorite`, `line_items` are also deleted. Why?

```
module CurrentFavorite
  def set_favorite
    if user_signed_in?
      set_user_favorite
    else
      if session[:favorite]
        @favorite = Favorite.find(session[:favorite])
      else
        @favorite = Favorite.create
        session[:favorite] = @favorite.id
      end
    end
  end
  def set_user_favorite
    if session[:favorite]
      if current_user.favorite.nil?
        @favorite = Favorite.find(session[:favorite])
        session[:favorite] = nil
        @favorite.update(user: current_user)
      else
        #block with error
        session_favorite = Favorite.find(session[:favorite])
        @favorite = Favorite.find_by(user: current_user)
        session_favorite.line_items.each do |line_item|
          line_item.update(favorite: @favorite)
        end
        session[:favorite] = nil
        session_favorite.destroy
        @favorite
      end
    else
      if current_user.favorite.nil?
        @favorite = current_user.build_favorite
        @favorite.save
      else
        @favorite = Favorite.find_by(user: current_user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
LineItem Update (0.7ms)  UPDATE "line_items" SET "favorite_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "line_items"."id" = ?  [["favorite_id", 1], ["updated_at", "2020-06-07 05:19:54.653064"], ["id", 13]]
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:31
   (12.9ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:31
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:31
  Movie Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE "movies"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:31
  LineItem Update (0.7ms)  UPDATE "line_items" SET "favorite_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "line_items"."id" = ?  [["favorite_id", 1], ["updated_at", "2020-06-07 05:19:54.674229"], ["id", 14]]
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:31
   (3.6ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:31
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:34
  LineItem Destroy (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ?  [["id", 13]]
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:34
  LineItem Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ?  [["id", 14]]
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:34
  Favorite Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."id" = ?  [["id", 10]]
  ↳ app/models/concerns/current_favorite.rb:34
```

Comment: Do you have `dependent: :destroy` on the model?

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: Yes of course .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_favorite` still has the set of `line_items` associated with it.  For performance reasons, Rails does not automatically reload the `line_items` before destroying the `session_favorite` so it doesn't recognize that the `line_items` are now associated with a different `favorite`.

To prevent the `line_items` being destroyed, refresh the association before doing the destroy:

```
session_favorite.line_items.reload
session_favorite.destroy
```

Comment: yes. it works, thanks. I could not understand why the models continue to be associated.